# Size of exported MX files

Tags: export, import, size

I have a problem with the following piece of Mathematica code:

```
A = Import["fileA.mx"];
B = Import["fileB.mx"];
```

The following evaluates to `True`:

```
A === B
```

however the size of one file is about 10 times greater then the size of the other one.

Both files were created in Mathematica using the same `Export["<some file>.mx" , <some expression>]` incantation. What's going on here?

Comment: Are you sure they were both created with `Export` and not with `DumpSave`?

Comment: Export was used for both A and B. 

I think I figured out what was going on.It looks like it all boils down to how MX stores files. I'll use a small example (in reality the tables were much larger), exporting: 
{Table[0 , {64} , {64}] , 1 , 2 , 3 , {Table[0 , {64} , {64}]}}
will produce a much larger MX file size then:
{zerotable , 1 , 2 , 3 , {zerotable}}
with
zerotable = Table[0 , {64} , {64}]
evaluated beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured out what was going on.It looks like it all boils down to how MX stores files. I'll use a small example (in reality the tables were much larger), exporting:

`{Table[0 , {64} , {64}] , 1 , 2 , 3 , {Table[0 , {64} , {64}]}}`

will produce a significantly larger MX file size then exporting:

`{zerotable , 1 , 2 , 3 , {zerotable}}`

with

`zerotable = Table[0 , {64} , {64}]`

evaluated beforehand.

Comment: Interesting find. Particularly as `Export` doesn't have `HoldRest` on it...

Answer (score 0):

Just as an extension on user34705's answer, as that had me very intrigued, the way [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html) works with the [`"MX"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/MX.html) format is by passing the values to `` System`Private`ConvertersPrivateDumpSymbol `` and calling [`DumpSave`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DumpSave.html) on that.

The fascinating thing is that, even for something like:

```
With[{z = Table[0, {64}, {64}]},
 With[{f = Export[CreateFile[], {z, z, z}, "MX"]},
  (DeleteFile[f]; #) &@FileByteCount[f]
  ]
 ]
```

we get the smaller byte count.

And this is despite the fact that `` System`Private`ConvertersPrivateDumpSymbol `` stores the true expression.

So somehow it knows, internally, that `z` inside that is shared whereas with the explicit version it does not.

No idea how it knows that, but it probably has to do with [`Share`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Share.html)

A very cool find by user34705.