# Storing import / export formats for automatic loading

Tags: export, import, customization

So for dredging stuff out of symbol definitions for looking at [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147866/38205) I found there's this:

```
System`ConvertersDump`$FormatsDirectory := 
  Catch[
   Quiet @ Select[
     {
      FileNameJoin @ {$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Formats"},
      FileNameJoin @ {$BaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Formats"},
      FileNameJoin @ {$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Formats"}
      },
     DirectoryQ
     ],
   SystemException["SandboxProtected", ___],
   Function @ Quiet @ Select[
      {
       FileNameJoin @ {$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", 
         "Formats"}
       },
      DirectoryQ
      ]
   ];
```

Which appears to be used by the I/O system for storing file formats. And looking at the `"MX"` Export.m we find it just registers an exporter.

Has anyone used this, though? What exactly can I do in one of these format files? How exactly are they used? (at least one form seems clear, but there might be subtleties or possibilities I'm missing)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, what do you want to do in those files? p.s. have you seen: [tutorial/DevelopingAnExportConverter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DevelopingAnExportConverter.html)?

Comment: @Kuba I have, but have never actually used that. I was interested in whether or not these took a specific syntax past simply registering an exporter or if it's just a directory for look up for I/O registering. For example the Stylesheets require a set syntax and documentation requires all sorts of little tweaks to get it to work just right. Of course both of those are notebook directories, while these are just .m files. But, on the other hand, service connections need you to return a specific thing, so it could be like that. (And I was being lazy and didn't want to research it right now...)